# MySQL database contains quotes encoded and unencoded and it's breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, html-entities

Example database value is `&#39;12345'` which is assigned to a PHP variable `$name`.

This value is used in a javacript onclick event for example:

```
onclick="assign('<?php echo $name;?>')
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

```
onclick="assign('<?php echo $name;?>')
// output: onclick="assign(''12345'')

onclick="assign('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>')
// output: onclick="assign('&#39;12345'')

onclick="assign('<?php echo addslashes($name);?>')
// output: onclick="assign(''12345\'')

onclick="assign('<?php echo htmlspecialchars(addslashes($name));?>')
// output: onclick="assign('&#39;12345\'')
```

The last version works but I'm thinking there must be a better method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use language aware escaping routines where possible. `addslashes` is almost never the right choice.

In this case, `json_encode` will do the job as JSON is a subset of the bit of JavaScript that describes literals. Note it will also add the quotes to indicate that it is a string.

Once you make it safe for JavaScript, your existing choice of `htmlspecialchars` is the right one to make that JavaScript safe for embedding in an HTML attribute value.

```
onclick="assign(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($name));?>)
```

You could also consider using a `data-` attribute to store the data in, and then binding your event handlers with `addEventListener`.

Comment: @RolandStarke — Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: That results in `onclick="assign('&quot;#039;12345'&quot;');">` which breaks because of the double quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `onclick="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('assign('+json_encode($name)+')');?>`. `'assign('+json_encode($name)+')'` for the js part, and then `htmlspecialchars( ... )` for the html part.

Comment: @xylar — That problem was fixed before you made the comment.

Comment: @t.niese — You *could* put all the JS in a string and then HTML encode it, but since the handwritten part is already HTML safe, you don't need to.