# MySQL statement fails due to encoded quotes

Tags: mysql, encoding

Following on from this question [MySQL database contains quotes encoded and unencoded and it's breaking javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728198/mysql-database-contains-quotes-encoded-and-unencoded-and-its-breaking-javascrip)

I am executing this MySQL query:

```
DELETE  FROM `example` WHERE `name` = '&#039;12345&#039;'
```

However it fails because the value in the database is `&#039;12345'`. It seems that old data in the database has a mixture of encoded and unencoded quotes. Is it safe to to update all `'` to `&#039;` in the database?

Comment: Why would you store HTML entities in your database?!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I have made sure DB doesn't store any HTML entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases (yours included), store text without any "encoding".  That is, do not store htmlentities, store the actual characters, do not store unicode 'codes', store the actual characters, etc.

Do likewise for anything you need to compare to what is in the database.

You will, however, have to escape strings when building SQL statements.  Otherwise, you can't get quotes (in text) inside quotes (that are part of the SQL syntax.

That is, you will end up with this SQL when searching for that Irishman:

```
... WHERE `name` = 'O\'Brian'
```